# How do I solve the discord bot Undici proxy authorization header not being cleared in cross-origin redirection on fetch error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How do I solve the discord bot Undici proxy authorization header not being cleared in cross-origin redirection on fetch error? I install the discord.js source package, it says it was successful, but later when I give the node .\app.js command, it says there is no discord.js package, I don't know what I should do.

```
import { Client } from "discord.js"
const client = new Client({
      intents: ["GUILDS"]
})

Client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("X Boots Active!")
})

client.login("TOKEN")
```